# Javascript: Append method is not working on IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, internet-explorer-11

I have an issue about javascript on IE11. I have the function with scenario:

- Click on category parent
- Show all products belong to this category
- Click one product -> jump to detail page
- The link with href "name of category > product name" will be shown

I tested on Chrome and Firefox. It works fine but on IE11, the category is missing

This is the code which I implemented for the category part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lct = location;
if (typeof document.referrer != "undefined" && document.referrer != ""
  && history.length > 1) {
  var ref = document.createElement('a');
  ref.href = document.referrer;

  if (lct.origin == ref.origin) {
    var back = $('<a nohref rel="nofollow" id="category-name" class="back" onclick="history.back()">Category name</a>');
    $('.meta').append(back);
  }
}
</script>
```

Does anyone know the reason? Thanks

P/S: I tried to read the console in IE11, they said "Object doesn't support this action" in this line

```
var url = new URL(window.location);
```

and "XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3."

Does anyone have a suggestion? :(

Comment: the above code is working fine with other browsers ? One doubt What are you  expecting from `back` variable ? Just HTML content or anything else

Comment: @Ramkee: Yes. It's working properly on all browser, except IE11 :(
 "back" contents only HTML code

Comment: Can you check control entering in 'if' condition block or not?

Comment: @Hanif: Yes. If condition still works.

Comment: But it is working for me you can try by removing '$' symbol from html string because append() method expect string not jQuery object. Like that: "var back = '<a nohref rel="nofollow" id="category-name" class="back" onclick="history.back()">Category name</a>';"

Comment: @Hanif: I tried this one too, and no changes happen. I read the IE console, it says "Object doesn't support this action" with this line (in my project but on the header part)
var url = new URL(window.location);

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 11 does not support element.append.

Instead of element.append try element.appendChild. Works with IE and all browsers. And does the same thing.